# stop Autoplay progress timer when user moseenter on the swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I want stop the swiper slider and autoplayTimeLeft when the user mouseenter on the locationBord and start swiper slider and autoplayTimeLeft again when the user mouseleave locationBord.
But in this code, when the user's mouse is placed on the locationBord, autoplayTimeLeft stops, but when the user mouseleaves, the time takes a negative number.
Thank you for guiding me where my code is wrong.[image]

```js
const progressCircle = document.querySelector(".autoplay-progress svg");
const progressContent = document.querySelector(".autoplay-progress span");
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiperLanding", {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  speed: 700,
  loop: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 3000,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  effect: "fade",
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  on: {
    autoplayTimeLeft(s, time, progress) {
      progressCircle.style.setProperty("--progress", 1 - progress);
      progressContent.textContent = `${Math.ceil(time / 1000)}s`;
    },
  },
});

var locationBord = document.querySelectorAll(".locationBord");
var titleProject = document.querySelectorAll(".infoProject .titleProject");
var linkProjact = document.querySelectorAll(".infoProject .linkProjact");

locationBord.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < titleProject.length; i++) {
      titleProject[i].parentNode.classList.add("dark");
    }
    swiper.autoplay.stop();
  });

  element.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < titleProject.length; i++) {
      titleProject[i].parentNode.classList.remove("dark");
    }
    swiper.autoplay.start();
    progressCircle.style.setProperty("--progress", 1); // Reset progressCircle
    progressContent.textContent = "3s"; // Reset progressContent
  });
});

locationBord.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < linkProjact.length; i++) {
      linkProjact[i].parentNode.classList.add("dark");
    }
    swiper.autoplay.stop();
  });

  element.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < linkProjact.length; i++) {
      linkProjact[i].parentNode.classList.remove("dark");
    }
    swiper.autoplay.start();
    progressCircle.style.setProperty("--progress", 1); // Reset progressCircle
    progressContent.textContent = "3s"; // Reset progressContent
  });
});
```

```css
.landingSlider {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 35px);
}

.landingSlider .swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.landingSlider .swiper-slide:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background: rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.5);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(32, 32, 32, 0) 0%, rgba(32, 32, 32, 1) 100%);
}

.landingSlider .swiper-slide img {
  height: calc(100vh - 35px);
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.locationTitleProject,
.locationLinkProjact {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  width: calc(40vw + 90px);
  z-index: 2;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.locationTitleProject {
  top: 100px;
  right: 50px;
}

.locationLinkProjact {
  top: 180px;
  right: 100px;
}

.infoProject {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.infoProject.dark {
  opacity: 1;
}

.infoProject .titleProject,
.infoProject .linkProjact {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.infoProject .titleProject {
  top: 115px;
  right: 60px;
}

.infoProject .linkProjact {
  top: 220px;
  right: 120px;
}

.autoplay-progress {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  bottom: 16px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.autoplay-progress svg {
  --progress: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke: white;
  fill: none;
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(125.6 * (1 - var(--progress)));
  stroke-dasharray: 125.6;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<section class="landingSlider">
  <div class="locationTitleProject locationBord"></div>
  <div class="locationLinkProjact locationBord"></div>
  <div class="swiper swiperLanding">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/nebula_brown.png" alt="" />
        <div class="infoProject">
          <div class="titleProject">
            <h2>
              title of My Project 1
            </h2>
          </div>

          <div class="linkProjact">
            <a href="">Link of My project</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="infoProject">
          <div class="titleProject">
            <h2>
              title of My Project 1
            </h2>
          </div>

          <div class="linkProjact">
            <a href="">Link of My project</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back04.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="infoProject">
          <div class="titleProject">
            <h2>
              title of My Project 1
            </h2>
          </div>

          <div class="linkProjact">
            <a href="">Link of My project</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="autoplay-progress">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48">
              <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="20"></circle>
            </svg>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed same issue and discovered that `effect: "fade"` was causing the problem. Not sure why yet, but try removing the effect to test the scenario.